# UnboundLocalError in multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a long code of calculations which takes parameters in `.txt` file, after calculations creates a new `.txt` file and save there a data. Here, for example, I show only the small first part of it where I construct the desired file name, look for it in the directory, open it read the parameters.

```
def target_func(k):
    dir_path = os.getcwd()
    for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
        if file.endswith(".txt") and 'Focuses{}'.format(k) in file:
            print(os.path.join(dir_path, file))
            print(file)
            param_file = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
    with open(param_file, 'r') as f:
        param_temp = f.readlines()
        param_list = []
        for i in range(len(param_temp) - 1):                   
            temp = param_temp[i].replace(',','').replace(';','').split()
            param_list.append([float(x) for x in temp])           


if __name__ == '__main__':
    numList = []
    for k in range(1,7):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=target_func, args=(k, ))
        p.start()
        print('Process number {} is running'.format(k))
        numList.append(p)

    for p in numList:
        p.join()

    print('End of calculations')
```

When I test this `target_func()` in the parent python interpreter it's ok. But when I try to execute this code in the `cmd(windows)` it breaks down with error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'param_file' referenced before assignment
```

I have no idea how to declare the variables inside the process. I looked for solution a few days but the only that I could find was the information of two kinds:

1. the discussions about process message exchange and share memory or data;
2. lots of the same toy and useless examples of executing the code which prints process id and number.

My task is to run 6 independent processes which won't interact no way. Each of them should consume 6 different `.txt` parameter files, make some calculations and save the results to 6 new different `.txt` result files. Nothing more. Could someone get me any advises how to do such a way?

Comment: The first `for` loop is simply not finding a matching file, and therefore `param_file` never gets assigned a value.  We can't tell from the information provided whether this is due to the current directory not being what you expect, or the filenames not quite matching the pattern the code is looking for.  Printing out the results of `os.listdir()` in each process will probably give a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pre-define the `param_file` variable outside the `for` loop *(as `None`, for example)*, so that in case it doesn't get defined inside the `for` loop *(happens when the `if` block within the `for` loop never gets executed)*, the variable will still be defined.

That way, you will be able to use the `param_file` variable after the `for` loop with an `if` statement that checks if the variable is `None` or not.

```
def target_func(k):
    dir_path = os.getcwd()
    param_file = None
    for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
        if file.endswith(".txt") and 'Focuses{}'.format(k) in file:
            print(os.path.join(dir_path, file))
            print(file)
            param_file = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
    if param_file is None:
        print("File not found")
    else:
        with open(param_file, 'r') as f:
            param_temp = f.readlines()
            param_list = []
            for i in range(len(param_temp) - 1):                   
                temp = param_temp[i].replace(',','').replace(';','').split()
                param_list.append([float(x) for x in temp])
```